# Origin of 'diff' tool

Tags: historical-research, computers

I can't seem to find any evidence that would place the origin of diff tool to the year 1972 (as stated on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)). So where is any initial research paper on it, first release, source code?

Comment: Sorry - my PDP-11 dies last week so I can't any longer retrieve any of it's original UNIX source files to verify their time stamps.

Comment: What exactly are you challenging? I can assure you, from personal knowledge, that by summer 1981 the *diff* functionality was ubiquitous on both popular DEC operating systems: *UNIX* and *VAX/VMS*.

Comment: Not sure if we're looking a the same Wikipedia, but the page states development on it happened in the early 70's and first shipped with Unix in 1974. Where is the 1972 coming from?

Comment: As @Giter says, Wikipedia doesn't seem to say 1972. Please clarify if this was a typo, or if you meant something else. BTW, wiki also links to a 1976 paper on the program, where the developer remarked "in two year we have had brought to our attention only one jackpost" which seems to match the timeline given.

Comment: You might want to ask this over on StackOverflow or ServerFault, the former being more for coding/development questions.

Answer (score 7):

The Unix Heritage Society shows that while *diff*'s [man page appeared in V6](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?filesearch=diff.1) (1975), its [source code appeared in V5](https://www.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s1/diff1.c) (1974). The algorithm is described there as being "due to Harold Stone".